# After multiplying $x_{\min}$ by $a$ and adding $b$, $x_{\min}$ still minimal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question looks very clear and trivial, but this is why I have difficult prove it.

If I hava a group $X$ of *real* and *positive* numbers: $X:=\{x_1,...,x_{\text{min}},...x_k\}$.

$x_{\min}$ denotes the smallest number.

I am trying to prove that if I apply the function $f(x)=a\cdot x+b$ on each element in $X$ so $x_{\min}$ still the smallest number after applying the function $f(x)$.

Here $a,b\in \mathbb R^+$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x < y$ (that is, $y - x$ is positive). Then if $a > 0$, $ax < ay$ (two positive numbers multiplied together gives a positive number, and $a(y - x) = ay - ax$). Now, $ax + b < ay + b$ ($(ay + b) - (ax + b) = ay - ax$), which implies your result.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ x_0:= x_{\min}$. Since $a>0$ we get $ax_0 \le ax$ for all $x \in X$ and therefore

$f(x_0)=ax_0+b \le ax+b=f(x)$ for all $x \in X$.